# Observer still receiving events after being disposed in cell RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, observable, rx-swift

I'm using RxSwift for form handling in collection view and table view. I am facing an issue.

I have a single selection list component and I am creating `DisposeBag` every time while configuring to remove all previous subscribers. `onDisposed` method is called for both but I still receive duplicate `onNext` events. This works fine in that start but when I reload the collection view or the table view I am facing this issue. Please let me know is there something I am doing wrong or is this bug in library.

```
var selectedIndex = Variable<Int?>(nil)

func configureRx(sender: RxRow<Int>) {

    dateVarDisposable = DisposeBag()

    selectedIndex
        .asObservable()
        .subscribe(onNext: {[weak self] (index) in
            self?.selectRow(selectedIndex: index)
            }, onDisposed: {

                print("")
        })
        .addDisposableTo(disposableBag)

    sender.dataVariable.asObservable()
        .debug(self.stringTag, trimOutput: false)
        .subscribe(onNext: { (sender) in
            self.selectedIndex.value = sender
        }, onDisposed: {
    })
        .addDisposableTo(disposableBag)        
}
```

Comment: Where do you call `configureRx` method? I guess you need to `dispose` the subscription on `prepareForReuse` method...

Comment: configureRx is being called on cellForRow
and yes I've tried using dispose on prepareForReuse

Comment: Perhaps because .addDisposableTo() method is deprecated in favour of .disposed(by: disposeBag)

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/issues/821. There's a special category for cells - `reuseBag`